# Convert absolute paths into relative path for rsync

Tags: command-line, path, rsync

I try to sync to folders, but with exceptions made by tags.
So I learned, that I need different commands to build up that job.
First I create a file of excluded files, which have a tag in orange or red set.

Then I call rsync with this output file as the no-do-list.
But the content of the file is an absolute file name, while rsync seems to need relative path.

This is what I already have (need local language for names!):

```
mdfind -onlyin . "kMDItemUserTags == 'Orange' || kMDItemUserTags == 'Rot'" > excluded.txt
```

And this is the one I need to get run:

```
rsync -avz --exclude-from "excluded.txt" source/ destination/
```

Any ideas?

Additional infos for better reading:
Now with "sed", I get:

```
./Gruppe/A-Teens
./Gruppe/A-Teens/A - Teens - Mama Mia.mp3
./Gruppe/A-Teens/A - Teens - Super Trouper.mp3
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Again everything is copied. Actual statements:

```
cd /Users/serveruser/Desktop/fasttemp/temp/Unser/Songs

mdfind -onlyin . "kMDItemUserTags == 'Orange' || kMDItemUserTags == 'Rot'" | sed 's|/Users/serveruser/Desktop/fasttemp/temp/Unser/Songs|.|' > excluded.txt
rsync -avz --exclude-from "excluded.txt" /Users/serveruser/Desktop/fasttemp/temp/Unser/Songs/ /Users/serveruser/Desktop/fasttemp/temp/Unser/Backup/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need to remove the leading part of the path, you can use `sed` to make it relative.

```
mdfind -onlyin . "kMDItemUserTags == 'Rot'" | sed 's|/PATH/TO/REMOVE/||' > excluded.txt
```